# How to check additional conditions in Laravel login?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am self taught Laravel.
I am trying to add more conditions for laravel login, with custom messages, but the error is never thrown !.I am trying to check if the user is not locked AND if email is verified.
here is my code in LoginController:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $valid = $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    ); // this will return true or false.
    if ($valid) { //if credentials are valid, check additional conditions.
        $user = $this->guard()->user();
        if ($user->email_verified_at == null || $user->locked == true) {
            $valid = false;
            return $valid;
        } else {
            $this->createUserFolder(); // if the login is successfull.
            $valid = true;
            return $valid;
        }
    }
    $valid = false;
    return $valid;
}

protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)//this will get triggered if the method above (attemptLogin(Request $request))  returns false.
{
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => $request['password'],
    ];
    $valid= Auth::attempt($credentials);
    if ($valid== false) { //if user credentials are incorrect
        $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors($errors);
    } else { // //if user credentials are correct
        $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();

        if ($user->locked == '1') {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                $this->username() => [trans('auth.locked')],
            ])->redirectTo('login');
        } else {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                $this->username() => [trans('auth.notactivated')],
            ])->redirectTo('login');
        }
    }
}

public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::logout();
    \Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $this->guard()->logout();
    \Session::flush();
    return redirect(\URL::previous());
}
```

Is it possible to use sendFailedLoginResponse for multiple conditions as above ?
What is wrong with my code ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Not sure if anyone was able to solve it but I couldn't, any help would be really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I find the answer as below:

protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)//this will get triggered if the method above (attemptLogin(Request $request))  returns false.
{
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => $request['password'],
    ];
    $valid = Auth::attempt($credentials);

    if ($valid == false) { //if user credentials are incorrect
        $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];
         Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors($errors);
    } else { // //if user credentials are correct check additional conditions
        $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();`enter code here`
        if ($user->locked == 1) {
            $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.locked')];
            Auth::logout();
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                $this->username() => [trans('auth.locked')],
            ]);
        } else {
            $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.notactivated')];
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
                ->withErrors($errors);
        }
    }
}
```